# How do extract urls from this page

Tags: php, regex, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to use curl to get some data from the web. What I have is a url like `somewebsite.com`. On this website, there's a whole bunch of `<divs>` that have a `class="control-element"` and have this markup:

```
<div class="control-element">
   <a href="http://someurl.com/and/some/path">Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

How should I extract the url and the anchor text for each of these links? Should I be using regex for this? or what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this particular case you could be just fine using **[file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** instead of **[cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)**.

For html parsing take a look at **[Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**.

If you don't want to use any 3-rd party libraries, here is an example using regex:

```
$doc = file_get_contents("http://someurl.com/");
preg_match_all('/<div class="control-element">(.*)<\/div>/isU', $doc, $matches);
$co = count($matches[1]);
for($i = 0; $i<$co;$i++)
{
    preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/isU', $matches[1][$i], $matches2);
    echo("URL: ".$matches2[1][0]." Anchor: ".$matches2[2][0]."<br>");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I want to install and use an external library for this.

Comment: file_get_contents() is not an external library, click the link that the develroot posted. It's a native PHP function.

Comment: i have edited my post and added a example using only php's built-in functions. check that

Comment: also if you want to use CURL, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php .. you can't get better documentation. But you may have to enable, uncomment it in your PHP.ini file if your not seeing it with phpinfo().